# Performance comparison between Filename Matching Vs. Partition Pruning

Tags: optimization, hive, amazon-athena, presto

I have a problem where there are files being created every 15 minutes so in a month I will have ~ 2880 files. In a year I will have 35,000 files! Compaction may be an option, which will mean I have 1 parquet file per hour = 8760 files!

However I was wondering how is **comparing filenames** using `"$path"` different than using **partitions**? Partition pruning is done in a single thread and is not distributed on a Hadoop Cluster. So if I have 35,000 files divided into year=????/day=365/hour=24/4 files each then, **Will the  performance of comparing file names same as using partition pruning?**

PS: I know I can archive older files.

[Athena Optimizations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some considerable overhead of handling a split, so it is virtually always better to filter them out on the coordinator. For the same reason, you want to avoid large number of small files (I don't know if your per 15 minutes files are small though).

Now, partition pruning and `"$path"` conditions are both evaluated on the coordinator (if possible, e.g. `"$path"` condition uses no other columns, etc.), so they should behave the same.

Note also that having very large number of small partitions may lead to performance problems in some areas of the code (nothing specific, but it happened to be a problem more than once in the past). Thus, you may want to have bigger partitions anyway.

Comment: 1. Yes, I do not have anything else other than $path. 2. I am planning to archive the data i.e. `Insert into archive_table Select * from datat_able` every month maybe then somehow identify and drop the files from the source filesystem.